How to save a set variable into a csv o json file inside a GEN 2 in ADF
I got some issues trying to copy data from an swagger using a web activity and a set variable to get the variable from a copy activity, one of the things that I notice is that the response that I obtained from the web activity is:

and after that I save the information into a variable through a set variable activity, the result are the following:
Input:

Output:

Now I trying to convert this data into a JSON file to save it in a storage account but I can't do it with a copy activity. Any suggestions?

You can directly use copy activity with a JSON dataset of HTTP linked service as source and JSON dataset with your target linked service as sink.
Create HTTP linked service with your URL and authentication and attach it with a JSON dataset by following the above documentation. In the sink, create JSON dataset with your target linked service and give the JSON file name without importing the schema in the dataset.

Run the copy activity and it will copy the response JSON array into the required JSON file.
Result file:

Similarly, if you want to copy this to a csv file, you can use delimited text dataset in the sink instead of a JSON dataset, but you need to set the mapping as per the input JSON.

If your URL or authentication only supports through web activity, then you can try the below approach. In ADF, you cannot directly store the JSON into a file. You can use Delimited dataset for this.
First create a dummy csv file in the storage with a single value (only one value).
dummy.csv
1
Create the Delimited text dataset for this file and disable the First row as a header in the dataset and leave the remaining configurations as default.
For the sink, create another Delimited text dataset and give the <JSON_filename>.json as file name. Change the dataset configurations as shown below.

Now, take copy activity after your set variable activity and give these as source and sinks of the copy activity. In the copy activity source, create an additional column named new_column and give your string variable which contains the required JSON string.

Give the second delimited text dataset as sink of the copy activity. In the mapping, give the below expression as a dynamic content expression.
@json('{
                                    "type": "TabularTranslator",
                                    "mappings": [
                                        {
                                            "source": {
                                                "name": "new_column",
                                                "type": "String"
                                            },
                                            "sink": {
                                                "type": "String",
                                                "physicalType": "String",
                                                "ordinal": 1
                                            }
                                        }
                                    ],
                                    "typeConversion": true,
                                    "typeConversionSettings": {
                                        "allowDataTruncation": true,
                                        "treatBooleanAsNumber": false
                                    }
                                }')


Now, run the pipeline and it will generate the JSON file with required JSON content as shown below.
Result file:

